# Get element by offset into Sequence

Tags: swift, indexing, sequence

Suppose I have this sequence:

```
let fibSequence = sequence(state: (0, 1), next: { (state) -> Int in
    state = (state.1, state.0 + state.1)
    return state.0
})
```

I can do things like get the first 5 elements:

```
print(Array(fibSequence.prefix(5))) // => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

But how can I get *just* the element at index 5 (6th element)? (Or returning `nil` if the sequence terminates before the 5th element.) The best I could come up with is:

```
print(fibSequence.dropFirst(5).makeIterator().next() as Any) // => Optional(8)
```

Is there a build in method to perform something like this?

Comment: Hi, has my answer helped you with this question?

Comment: @DavidRees Ah thanks for following it up. I didn't notice it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, there isnt currently a way to index the sequences but it's fairly easily made with an extension on Sequence:

```
extension Sequence {
    subscript(index: Int) -> Self.Iterator.Element? {
        return enumerated().first(where: {$0.offset == index})?.element
    }
}
```

This means you can easily index the sequence like this:

```
print(fibSequence[8])
```

Alternatively I found you can use this logic to index a specific element which removes the cast to Any warnings

```
let fibSequence = sequence(state: (0, 1), next: { (state) -> Int in
    state = (state.1, state.0 + state.1)
    return state.0
})
print(fibSequence.enumerated().first(where: {$0.offset == 5})?.element)
```

Comment: I would advise against adding a subscript here; subscripts look like O(1) operations – `for i in 5 ..< n { print(fibSequence[i]) }` looks linear, but would be accidently quadratic. Also it will have quite confusing semantics for destructive sequences; for example consider `class Counter : Sequence, IteratorProtocol { var i = 0; func next() -> Int? { defer { i += 1 }; return i }}`. `let c = Counter(); print(c[5] == c[5])` returns false, which may be surprising, as a subscript doesn't look like a destructive operation.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree, you have perfectly demonstrated why there isnt a subscript method on a Sequence class.